# My project uses the Google+ API to login,which is deprecated now, need tips/advice to update

Tags: python, django, google-plus, google-oauth

I have a project currently deployed, in production, which uses the google+ API and the python social core (Django) ([social_core](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core)) to login almost all users, now the google+ apis are deprecated and I need to update the authentication system. Any tip, documentation or tutorial I can follow to make it?
I followed [this](https://fosstack.com/how-to-add-google-authentication-in-django/) tutorial to make the initial login but now that won't work in the near future.
This is a school project so I'm pretty much the only developer working with this, any help provided will be much appreciated :D

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Google document shows you how to migrate from Google+ to Google Sign-In. This is a step by step fairly detailed document on how to complete the conversion for the Google libraries part.

The important items to change on your backend:

1. Use the new Google OAuth 2.0 (OpenID Connect) endpoints. Use the [Discovery Document](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)
2. Replace the deprecated Google+ scopes.
3. Replace the Django OAuth Flows: [Using Django OAuth Flows](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django)

[Migrate from Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide)

Comment: Hi john, [social-auth-app-django](https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html) does the changes for oauth flows, may I know why do we need google api for oauth flow?

Comment: @JigarWala - Create a new question.